# Multiple plots using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
key, value_1, counts

1, "foo", 20
1, "bar", 45
1, "baz", 22
5, "bar", 24
2, "foo", 15
```

and so on..

Now, I want to plot multiple(bar) plots corresponding for each key based on counts of each value_1

So plot 1 is like
bar plot of `45,22, 20` (`sorted(["foo", "bar", "baz"])` values)

My noob way is to slice the dataframe by index and then plot it. But I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: A separate figure for each unique value of `'key'`?

Comment: It would help to see an example plot, or the code for your "noob way" to understand what you're asking

Comment: What do you think is not pythonic enough in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby and plot

```
for name, grp in df.groupby('key'):
    grp.plot.bar('value_1', 'counts', title = name)
```